# How do i write from a file in a matrix in python

Tags: python, file, matrix

I've got this c code

```
 FILE *f,*g;
 f=fopen("sudoku.in","r");
    void read()
    {                                       

        int i,j;
        for(i=1; i<=9; i++)
            for(j=1; j<=9; j++)
                fscanf(f,"%d",&a[i][j]);

    }
```

and i dont know how to read from a file in a matrix in python

```
 fileRead = open('sudoku.in', 'r')
 fileWrite = open('sudoku.out', 'w')
```

Comment: You could start by getting the string content of the file

Comment: Are the numbers in the file organized by lines, each line of nine values?

Comment: This may depend on the format of the file. Could you provide an example with editing your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your file looks like

> ```
> 123456789\n
> 987654321\n
> ...
> ```

Then something like

```
with open('sudoku.in', 'r') as R:
    a = [[int(c) for c in l] for l in R.readlines()]
```

Should give you `a` as a list of lists (a list of rows, each row is a list of integers).

If the values in each line are separated by spaces, it's even simpler:

```
with open('sudoku.in', 'r') as R:
    a = [l.split() for l in R.readlines()]
```

See [`readlines()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm) and [`split()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try out numpy, As easy as

```
import numpy as np

mat = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=" ")
```

full detail check out the documentation [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)